# Pytest parametrize test case share a class variable

Tags: python, pytest

I have recently started using pytest and I have written a following class.

```
import pytest
import yaml
import random

testcases = list()
class TestSample(object):
    test_yml_file = "/tmp/test_inputs.yml"

    yamlTestList = list()
    with open(test_yml_file, 'r') as testYamlFile:
        yamlTestList = yaml.load(testYamlFile)

    global testcases
    testcases = []

    for d in yamlTestList['testcases']:
        temp = dict()
        for k,v in d.items():
            temp[k] = v
        testcases.append((temp['testcase'],temp))

    last_value = 2

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(self):
        test_sample = TestSample()

    @pytest.mark.debug
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(('testname', 'testInput'), testcases)
    def test_run(self,testname,testInput):
        if last_value >= 10:
            last_value += random.randint(1,10)
```

Current issue is -
For each parameterize test, last_value is set to 2 always. How can we use value of 'last_value' variable changed in previous test case into the current test case?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want the variable `last_value` to be dynamic? It should take the value of the current test case, right?

Comment: I want to check value of that variable set by previous test case.

Comment: You can use "yaml.safe_load" instead of "yaml.load" because it's more safe.

By the way you might have a look at this project because what you are doing it seems very close to what pytest-play already does. See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-play/tree/features (to be released soon in 2.0.0 YAML support, at this time of writing check the features branch)
It supports YAML scenarios, markers and test parametrization

Answer (score 8):

### Answer:

You will need to instantiate the `lastvalue` variable in an outer scope, from which the parameterized function can be called, and not in the test class itself. This is because of how the parameterization works with pytest. Each function call with each individual parameter set exists in a separate scope, so in your code you are basically resetting the `lastvalue` variable to 2 each time before calling the function.

### Solution 1:

I don't recommend globals, but following your example, this demonstrates what I am talking about.

```py
last_value = 0


class TestSample(object):
    testcases = [("name1", 1), ("name2", 2), ("name3", 3), ("name4", 4)]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(('testname', 'testInput'), testcases)
    def test_run(self, testname, testInput):
        global last_value
        if last_value >= 10:
            last_value += random.randint(1, 10)
        else:
            last_value += 5

        print(last_value)
```

Note also that I added an else clause to the function to test this with. Even if the parameterization worked similar to a loop within a single class instance, the `lastvalue` variable would have never changed anyways in your example code as the `if last_value >= 10` clause never has a chance to be met and thus the `lastvalue` increment never actually occurs.

### Best Solution:

Instead of using globals I would recommend using a pytest fixture with a "class" scope. You can read about fixtures and fixture scopes [in the pytest docs here.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session)

```py
@pytest.fixture(name="sample_manager", scope="class")
def sample_manager_fixture():
    class SampleManager:
        def __init__(self):
            self.last_value = 0

    return SampleManager()


class TestSample:
    testcases = [("name1", 1), ("name2", 2), ("name3", 3), ("name4", 4)]

    def test_order(self, sample_manager):
        print(sample_manager.last_value)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(('testname', 'testInput'), testcases)
    def test_run(self, testname, testInput, sample_manager):
        if sample_manager.last_value >= 10:
            sample_manager.last_value += random.randint(1, 10)
        else:
            sample_manager.last_value += 5

        print(sample_manager.last_value)
```

The `sample_manager_fixture()` fixture function returns a `SampleManager` class instance when it is passed to a test function. Pytest handles all of this behind the scenes, so all you need to do is include the fixture name (declared explicitly in my case) as a parameter. The fixture scope defines the "lifespan" of each particular object instance returned from the fixture. So, setting the scope to "class" for the fixture notifies pytest that you want all test functions in a particular class to share the same instance of the object returned from the fixture. You can return any object, with any structure, from fixtures that you want, so they are a really powerful tool to manage data across your tests.

Comment: As a note, the `test_order()` function in the last code example was added to show how the object instance returned from the fixture is shared between the two test functions. Placed where it is, before the `test_run()` function, it prints out 0, but if you move it after the `test_run()` function, it shows clearly that both functions share the same `SampleManager` instance, in addition to what order the functions receive that instance.